# With XFCE power manager, how to turn both monitors asleep instead of one monitor?

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor, power-management

I'm using an ArchLinux with XFCE, and I encountered a problem.

I have two monitors, and I want both of them to be turned off when I am away from PC for X minutes. But it seems like only my primary monitor is turned off, and my second monitor stays on forever.

How can I make so XFCE power manager correctly turns off both of my monitors?

Comment: does the primary monitor actually go into suspend mode, or does the screensaver display a blank screen

Comment: As far as I can tell, it first goes into screensaver, and then into suspend mode.

Comment: switch the video cables betwen the two monitors

Comment: Ehm, so that only secondary monitor will be suspended? What's the point?